# System.Diagnostics.Process in F# - how to use it?

Tags: .net, f#

Can someone give me a very simple example of how one would, say, write an F# program to open Notepad? I keep running into a "File Not Found" exception, but there doesn't seem to be any reason for it - the StartInfo property is correctly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't set the startinfo properties, but not specifying a path to notepad should work:

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.net
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe", "NoFile.txt");
```

Comment: Actually it turns out that the issue was because I was trying to launch Notepad from C:\Windows, and apparently it didn't like that.